# CUDA + VS2010 without VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I'd like to know whether it's possible to program for CUDA without installing VS2008.
At the moment I've got VS2010 installed on my primary development machine and I don't wanna mess things up installing VS2008. Furthermore, I would no use for it aside from CUDA.
I've been doing a few searches and it looks like it should be possible to circumvent this dependency installing a version of the Windows SDK, however the information was unclear and I'm usure about the version of the SDK I should install and of the efficacy of such workaround.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Not an answer to your question per se, but installing VS2008 won't mess anything up at all. I have three versions of VS installed myself; 2003, 2008 and 2010. There is even a "version selector" program that helps make sure solutions are loaded in the version of VS they were last saved in, automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been down that road before and things worked far from smooth (especially when I tried installing 2008 *after* 2010), so I'd really like to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuda still needs the vs2008 runtime so you have to have it installed. You can configure vs2010 to use that runtime (if you have vs2008 installed!) for a specific project.