# A error occurred when open a CUDA SDK example using VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda

I have installed cudatoolkit_3.2.16_win_64 and gpucomputingsdk_3.2.16_win_64. When I choose a example of the SDK, I get this error:

> The imported project "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\BuildCustomizations\NvCudaRuntimeApi.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path
>   in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on
>   disk. C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK
>   3.2\C\src\template\template_vc90.vcxproj

And in the Solution Explorer, it shows "template(unavailable)""the project file was unloaded".

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

3.2 now works with the latest bits. Horray! The simplest way to get this working is to install [NSight](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nsight.html) 1.51 and this gets you the build rules installed in the right place for 3.2.

Here are two tutorials on getting started with CUDA and Visual C++ 2010:

http://blog.cuvilib.com/2011/02/24/how-to-run-cuda-in-visual-studio-2010/

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2011/03/using-cuda-and-thrust-with-visual-studio-2010/

There's also a post on the NVIDIA forum:

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=184539

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't have v3.2 with VS2010 because it ain't supported yet.

But you could fallback to 3.1 if you would like to keep using VS2010:

[CUDA + VS2010 without VS2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966069/cuda-vs2010-without-vs2008/4064260#4064260)